# Rails - How to refresh an association after a save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a category with a list of items. The items have a position and the category has a relationship has_many :items, :order => "position". When a user updates a position value, I want to see its position. My position is a float to allow moving between rounded numbers.

```
pos=item.category.items.map(&:id)
current_position=pos.index(id.to_i)
item.save # want to refresh the relationship here
pos_new=item.categoty.items.map(&:id)
# grabbing this since just accessing item isn't updated if positioning has changed
item_new=Item.find(id)
pos_new=item_new.category.items.map(&:id)
new_position=pos_new.index(id)
if current_position!=new_position
  is_moved=true # sent back in JSON to propagate a dynamic change.
end
```

The above works but it seems really verbose. Is there a way for me to tell on item save that the category relationship needs to be refreshed since the order could be changed?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `item.reload` that will refetch the model from the database and next time you call an association, it will refetch it.

Answer (score 75):

For single-item associations:

```
book.reload_author
```

For other associations:

```
author.books.reload
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching

---

*In older versions of rails, before Rails 5, you could pass `true` to an association method as the first parameter to make it reload: `author.books(true)`.*

Comment: Who still comes to this answer from searching (like I just did): This behavior is no longer supported by rails. You get a deprecation warning. The new way for collections is to use the `reload` method on the collection proxy.

Comment: @klaustopher Thanks. Updated my answer.

Comment: "DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing an argument to force an association to reload is now deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Please call `reload` on the parent object instead. (called from <main> at (pry):2)"

Comment: why should we invoke this reload manually? isn't there anyway to do it automatically? thanks

Comment: @newBike You invoke this manually because you and not Rails knows when it is needed.  You might be setting values on models in memory and saving later, but reloading would clobber you change and set it back.  Also, when you update the value, then save, you already have the updated data in the object in memory, because you just set it before the database had the value.

Comment: Also @newBike it takes significant time to query the database, so if the value in the model is sufficient (it may be likely that it is up to date) there is a big benefit in performance to not query the database every time.

Answer (score 7):

Rails 4 will update your has_many/belongs_to associated objects for you when they change, but it will not re-run the query which means that even though the items in the category.items will be updated they will not be in order. Depending on the size of your tables you may want to use ruby to order the result or use category.reload to get them in order.

See the RailsGuides at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and look for inverse_of